# Dynamic reference to closed workbook in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I partially solved the problem that I initially had and figured that my description of the problem was a bit too detailed. I decided to rewrite my question so it's easier to understand the problem and people who are looking for the same thing can relate faster.

I've got several topic files (each with a different name) with 21 rows and 21 columns that need to be gathered into 1 file (called Summary). In Summary, I want a code that looks at a list of the topic names and then places a reference in the cells to the corresponding cells in the topic file. As you can see in the code below, I've accomplished a simplified version of this. It looks at the cell with the name of the first topic file and then created a reference for all rows and columns in that file.

```
Sub PullValue()
Dim path, file, sheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


path = Worksheets("Settings").Range("B23")
file = Worksheets("Consolidation").Range("A1")
sheet = "Overview"

For i = 2 To 22
    For j = 1 To 21
        Cells(i, j).Formula = "='" & path & "[" & file & ".xlsm]" & _
        sheet & "'!" & Cells(i - 1, j).Address & ""
    Next j
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This works as it should, but after that, it has to do this for all the files in that topic name table. I'll keep on trying, but help would be much appreciated, thanks.

If more info is required, don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks!
Bart

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and trial & error, I came up with my own solution. I'll share it here so people who are dealing with the same issue can get some input here.

I've added comments to the code so it's easier to understand.

```
Sub PullValue()
Dim path, file, sheet
Dim LastRow As Long, TopicCount As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, a As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'1. We count how many topics are written in the Topics table to decide the amount of loops
'I do this by checking the total rows in the table and subtract the empty ones
With Worksheets("Settings").ListObjects("Topics")

    TopicCount = .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - _
    Application.CountBlank(.DataBodyRange)

End With

'2. We loop the code for the amount of times we just calculated so it does it for all topics
'I'll make a note where we can find that a in the code
For a = 1 To TopicCount

    '3. In the consolidation sheet where all the data will be, we want to check what the
    'LastRow is in column A to get the starting point of where the data is entered
    With Worksheets("Consolidation")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    End With

    '4. This If function puts a spacing between the blocks of data if the LastRow is not the
    'first row. This is only to make it visually look better.
    If LastRow <> 1 Then

        LastRow = LastRow + 2

    End If

    '5. The first thing we want to do is put the name of the topic below the LastRow so it's
    'easy to check afterwards what topic the block of data belongs to. Here you can find the
    'a from the loop we have in the beginning.
    Cells(LastRow, "A").Value = [Topics].Cells(a, [Topics[Topics]].Column)

    '6. Locate where the path, file and sheet names are located in the document. Don't
    'forget to put the / at the end if it's a website or the \ if it's on your computer.
    'If you look to the code at comment number 7, we already have the .xlsm in the formula
    'so we don't need to enter that for the file.
    path = Worksheets("Settings").Range("D2")
    file = Worksheets("Consolidation").Cells(LastRow, 1)
    sheet = "Overview"

    'This is the core of the code and will the right reference in the right cell. This loops
    'for all the 21 rows and columns.
    For i = LastRow + 1 To LastRow + 21

        For j = 1 To 21

            Cells(i, j).Formula = "='" & path & "[" & file & ".xlsm]" & _
            sheet & "'!" & Cells(i - LastRow, j).Address & ""

        Next j

    Next i

Next a

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any questions you might have regarding the code, let me know. I hope this might help some people. Improvements are of course welcome as well.

Bart